# Fatal signal on glDrawArrays within onDrawFrame (GLSurfaceView.Renderer, SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener)

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, shader, textures

I am getting a Fatal Signal 11 after quite a few

```
GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

calls within my OnDrawFrame function. The textures are been drawn correctly before the crash, which I believe it means that my vertex and fragment shaders work fine.

What I am trying to do, is to blend two textures together using GLSurfaceView.Renderer and SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener.

The first texture is a live camera preview SurfaceTexture which works fine by its own. The second tetxure is just a bitmap image, which also works fine by its own. but combining them gives the crash.

My OnDrawFrame is as follows:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) { 
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    synchronized(this) { 
        if (updateSurface) {
            mSurface.updateTexImage();
            mSurface.getTransformMatrix(mSTMatrix);
            updateSurface = false;
        }
    } 

    maPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aPosition");
    maTextureHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aTextureCoord");
    muMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix"); 
    muSTMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uSTMatrix");
    muCRatioHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uCRatio");

    GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textures[0]);
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    int t1h = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation ( mProgram, "sTexture1" );
    //        GLES20.glUniform1i(t1h, textures[0]);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(t1h, 1);

    GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textures[1]);
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
    int t2h = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation ( mProgram, "sTexture2" );
    GLES20.glUniform1i(t2h, 2);

    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); 

    mTriangleVertices.position(0);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            4*5, mTriangleVertices);

    mTriangleVertices.position(3);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            4*5, mTriangleVertices);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0, mMMatrix, 0);  
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muSTMatrixHandle, 1, false, mSTMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniform1f(muCRatioHandle, mCameraRatio);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);
    //        GLES20.glFlush();
}
```

where mTriangleVertices is:

```
mTriangleVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mTriangleVerticesData.length
            * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
mTriangleVertices.put(mTriangleVerticesData).position(0);
```

and mTriangleVerticesData is:

```
private final float[] mTriangleVerticesData = {
    // X, Y, Z, U, V
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 0.f, 0.f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 1.f, 0.f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, 0, 0.f, 1.f,
    1.0f,   1.0f, 0, 1.f, 1.f,
};
```

Any tips, links or even code snippets would be much appreciated!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if this is the cause for the crash but you're assigning one too high texture ids for shader at least. For example;

```
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
int t1h = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation ( mProgram, "sTexture1" );
GLES20.glUniform1i(t1h, 1);
```

Should read

```
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
int t1h = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation ( mProgram, "sTexture1" );
GLES20.glUniform1i(t1h, 0);
```

Edit: Ah, this might be the cause for the crash:

```
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
        4*5, mTriangleVertices);
```

It should be

```
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
        4*5, mTriangleVertices);
```

More likely since you have two texture values per vertex.

Comment: Harism thank you for replying to both of my posts :) If I had enough reputation I would also give you an upvote :) This worked perfect!!